# Is possible use node-module in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I want use selenium-webdriver on chrome-extension
but that's module is back-end (node.js)
so require('fs') and another dependencies module not found in browser

but i found chrome-extension selenium-ide source
selenium-webdriver module is load in that's app

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide

How can build node-module on chrome-extension?

Comment: If the module uses API such as `fs` that aren't provided by the browser then you can't use it. There's probably no need to use webdriver, instead you might be able to implement what you want using chrome.debugger API.

Comment: @wOxxOm hum... ok i searching that api Thx for answer